# Как переместить столбец в таблице?

Tags: sqlite

нужно чтобы в таблицы столбцы были в такой последовательности: t1,t2,t6,t3,t4,t5.
Можно ли создать такой запрос, чтобы он переместил данной столбец, в нужное нам место, не пересоздавая заново таблицу?

***SQLite TABLE:***

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | t6 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  |
| 11 | 22 | 33 | 44 | 55 | 66 |
|111 | 222| 333| 444| 555| 666|
|1111|2222|3333|4444|5555|6666|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Зачем это нужно? Выбирайте столбцы в нужном порядке и все

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы таблица, выглядела так как изначально задумывалось. Нужно мне вставить столбец `t6` между `t2` и `t3` (таблица уже заполнена)

Comment: объясните толком что Вы хотите сделать? изменить порядок следования столбцов в таблице? не проще ли формировать результат путем указания столбцов в необходимом порядке? если же вам действительно хочется изменить физический порядок следования то тогда смотрите ответ @cheops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению, SQLite не поддерживает полноценный оператор `ALTER TABLE`, который бы позволил вам менять порядок следования столбцов. Поэтому для осуществления этой задачи придется выполнить целую последовательность операций. Один из возможных путей состоит в следующем. Создать рядом таблицу с нужной вам структурой

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
  t1 INTEGER,
  t2 INTEGER,
  t6 INTEGER,
  t3 INTEGER,
  t4 INTEGER,
  t5 INTEGER
);
```

Перегнать в нее данные из первоначальной таблицы

```
INSERT INTO
  new_table
SELECT
  t1, t2, t6, t3, t4, t5 FROM t;
```

Удалить старую таблицу

```
DROP TABLE t;
```

Переименовать новую таблицу, назначив ей имя старой таблицы

```
ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO t;
```